# Array pass by value by default & thread-safety

Tags: swift, multithreading, swift3, concurrency, thread-safety

Say I have a class which has an `Array` of object `Photo`:

```
class PhotoManager {
  fileprivate var _photos: [Photo] = []

  var photos: [Photo] {
      return _photos
  }
}
```

I read [one article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1) which says the following:

> By default in Swift class instances are passed by reference and
>   structs passed by value. Swift’s built-in data types like Array and
>   Dictionary, are implemented as structs.

Meaning that the above getter returns a copy of `[Photo]` array.

Then, that same article tries to make the getter thread-safe by refactoring the code to:

```
fileprivate let concurrentPhotoQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.raywenderlich.GooglyPuff.photoQueue",
                                                       attributes: .concurrent)
  fileprivate var _photos: [Photo] = []
  var photos: [Photo] {
    var photosCopy: [Photo]!
    concurrentPhotoQueue.sync {
        photosCopy = self._photos
    }
    return photosCopy
  }
```

The above code explictly make a copy of `self._photos` in getter.

My questions are:

1. If by default swift already return an copy (pass by value) like the article said in the first place, why the article copy again to `photosCopy` to make it thread-safe? I feel myself do not fully understand these two parts mentioned in that article.
2. Does Swift3 really pass by value by default for `Array` instance like the article says?

Could someone please clarify it for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In code example what you provided will be returned copy of `_photos`.
As wrote in article:

```
The getter for this property is termed a read method as it’s reading
the mutable array. The caller gets a copy of the array and is protected 
against mutating the original array inappropriately.
```

that's mean what you can access to `_photos` from outside of class, but you can't change them from there. Values of `photos` could be changed only inside class what make this array protected from it accidental changing.

2)Yes, `Array` is a value-type struct and it will be passed by value. You can easily check it in Playground

```
let arrayA = [1, 2, 3]
var arrayB = arrayA

arrayB[1] = 4 //change second value of arrayB

print(arrayA) //but arrayA didn't change
```

UPD #1

In article they have method `func addPhoto(_ photo: Photo)` what add new photo to `_photos` array what makes access to this property not thread-safe. That's mean what value of `_photos` could be changed on few thread in same time what will lead to issues.

They fixed it by writing photos on `concurrentQueue` with `.barrier` what make it thread-safely, `_photos` array will changed once per time

```
func addPhoto(_ photo: Photo) {
  concurrentPhotoQueue.async(flags: .barrier) { // 1
    self._photos.append(photo) // 2
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // 3
      self.postContentAddedNotification()
    }
  }
}
```

Now for ensure thread safety you need to read of `_photos` array on same queue. That's only reason why they refactored read method

Comment: I have posted two code snippets, what I am asking is the 1st code snippet which the article says the read method returns a copy of mutable array, my confusion is if that is the case why the author of the article refactor the code to the 2nd code snippet I posted that explictly copy the array to return if it is by default already return a copy of the array?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it doesn't answer my question clearly. What your update mentioned is what I already understood. My question is only about the "copy" part. Firstly, the author says by default in swift, array is a struct which is passed by value, which means by default, the read method already return a copy of the array. Then, why later it again copy the array explictly if by default it is copied in swift? it sounds to me like the code is copying the array twice.

Comment: @Leem.fin they made it not because it make `array copy`, but for protecting `_photos` array what is collect all photos(not `photos` property) from access outside of class. So you can't write directly to `_photos` property only thru `addPhoto(_ photo: Photo)` method

Comment: So the saying of "array by default return a copy in swift" is meant for `photos` property reader only?

Comment: @Leem.fin no, it mean what array is really return a copy in swift. But they made it only for to make `_photos` read-only outside from class. This is a main reason for existing of `photos` property. You see, `_photos` is a real container(you can read and write photos to him), and `photos` just represent his content and give access to all photos from outside the class

Comment: @Leem.fin making a copy of some collection means a complex task, which could be done 'atomically' to be thread-safe. If you would like to simply 'return a copy' you have to be sure that some part of your original collection is not modified while creating a copy. They make a copy in synchronized way in the example only for this reason. They make it the right way :-). I suggest you accept this answer as a valid answer.

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko no, it is not the reason. the reason to make a copy is explained in my note above.

Comment: @user3441734, why making a copy in synchronized way with concurrent queue makes the read method thread safe? Why not just use serial queue?

Comment: a serial queue will do the synchronization as well. did you read the whole article, where is your example from? https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1

Comment: I see. BTW, I also read this http://basememara.com/creating-thread-safe-arrays-in-swift/. It seems this way, no copy needed to read the array.

Comment: @Leem.fin calling the sync method on concurrent queue doesn't block the queue, so the var photos could be read from different threads in parallel. if you use a serial queue for reading, only one reading operation could be done in the same time.

Comment: @Leem.fin in the mentioned article he used the same 'copy' strategy, see how all the extensions are declared.

Comment: @Leem.fin check this https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-02-06-locks-thread-safety-and-swift.html

Comment: For other people who has the same question as me to better understand it, I would recommend to read comments and answers from all @TarasChernyshenko, user3441734 & CRD

Answer (score 1):

I'll address your questions in reverse:

> 2. Does Swift3 really pass by value by default for Array instance like the article says?

Simple Answer: Yes

But I'm guessing that is not what your concern is when asking "Does Swift3 *really* pass by value". Swift behaves *as if* the array is copied in its entirety but behind the scenes it optimises the operation and the whole array is not copied until, and if, it needs to be. Swift uses an optimisation known as copy-on-write (COW).

However for the Swift programmer *how* the copy is done is not so important as the *semantics* of the operation - which is that after an assignment/copy the two arrays are independent and mutating one does not effect the other.

> 1. If by default swift already return an copy (pass by value) like the article said in the first place, why the article copy again to photosCopy to make it thread-safe? I feel myself do not fully understand these two parts mentioned in that article.

What this code is doing is insuring that the copy is done in a thread-safe way.

An array is not a trivial value, it is implemented as multi-field struct and some of those fields reference other structs and/or objects - this is needed to support an arrays ability to grow in size, etc.

In a multi-threaded system one thread could try to copy the array while another thread is trying to change the array. If these are allowed to happen at the same time then things easily can go wrong, e.g. the array could change while the copy is in progress, resulting in an invalid copy - part old value, part new value.

Swift *per se* is **not** thread safe; and in particular it will not prevent an array from being changed while a copy is being performed. The code you have addresses this by using a GCD queue so that during any alteration to the array by one thread all other writes or reads to the array in any other thread are blocked until the alteration is complete.

You might also be concerned that their are multiple copies going on here, `self._photos` to `photoCopy`, then `photoCopy` to the return value. While *semantically* this is what happens in practice there will probably only be one complex copy (and that will be thread safe) as the Swift system will optimise.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I understand now! :)

Comment: Though I accepted the other answer, I recommend people also read @CRD's answer, it is helpful too.